# Changing Joint from Fixed to Revolute Breaks TF

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I'm fairly new to ROS and still learning. I've been struggling with this problem for a while, and I can't seem to solve it. I've dug through countless ROS Answers, but can't seem to find the solution.

I'm running through the [URDF Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20a%20URDF%20in%20Gazebo) and finished it. This is as in, if I run the last `13-diffdrive.launch` all starts up correctly. To prove to myself that I know how it works, I attempted to make R2D2's legs also rotate at his *shoulders*, by changing the joint from `fixed` to `revolute`, which also requires a few additional changes as well.

---

So first what I did was change the following in the `*.urdf.xacro` file:

```
<joint name="base_to_${prefix}_leg" type="fixed">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_leg"/>
      <origin xyz="0 ${reflect*(width+.02)} 0.25" />
</joint>
```

to

```
<joint name="base_to_${prefix}_leg" type="revolute">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_leg"/>
      <origin xyz="0 ${reflect*(width+.02)} 0.25" />
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>      
      <limit effort="1000.0" lower="0.0" upper="0.548" velocity="0.5"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
</joint>
```

by copying code from the `_gripper_joint`. When running the launch file again it opens RViz and Gazebo with a little wheel controlling interface. In Gazebo everything displays correctly, and I can see the new joint swiwels when I drive R2D2 around. But, in RViz the legs are displayed at the `origin` and not at the *shoulders*. **This because the TF Transform isn't published**. I double checked this using the command `rostopic echo /joint_states -n 1`, which didn't display the new shoulder joint.

---

According to the tutorial to get the joint state published you need to add a transmission. So added the transmission like below, again copying from the `_gripper_joint`.

```
<joint name="base_to_${prefix}_leg" type="revolute">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_leg"/>
      <origin xyz="0 ${reflect*(width+.02)} 0.25" />
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>      
      <limit effort="1000.0" lower="0.0" upper="0.548" velocity="0.5"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
</joint>
<transmission name="$base_to_${prefix}_trans">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <actuator name="$base_to_${prefix}_motor">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
      <joint name="$base_to_${prefix}_leg">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
</transmission>
```

This **breaks** a few things, and I don't understand where I'm going wrong. The symptoms that I see are the following:

- Gazebo still seems to display the bot correctly, but gripper retracts into the body with no command given. This makes me think that some joints are getting confused.
- In Gazebo I've lost control of the wheel, which is also why I think some joints are getting confused.
- In RViz only half of the bot is loaded.
- Nothing is being published in the `/joint_states` topic.
- In the terminal I get the following error message:

`[ERROR] [1586155354.004703965, 0.067000000]: This robot has a joint named "$base_to_right_leg" which is not in the gazebo model.`

`[FATAL] [1586154968.212960797, 0.255000000]: Could not initialize robot simulation interface`

---

The rest of the code is as it's in the final tutorial step. There is a `JointStateController`.

The most general problem for this `ERROR` is that the joint's child or parent link does not have mass/intertia, but this is isn't the case. This can be double checked by seeing the base code I'm using [here](https://github.com/ros/urdf_sim_tutorial/blob/master/urdf/13-diffdrive.urdf.xacro).

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Please let me know if I should supply more information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348509/changing-joint-from-fixed-to-revolute-breaks-tf/) by [Hein Wessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/53262/hein-wessels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-06**:
It would help (others) if you could show the complete urdf. It's a bit hard to figure out what the states of things is without it.

Also:

> According to the tutorial to get the joint state published you need to add a transmission.

this is (most likely) only true if/when using Gazebo, as the standard `joint_state_publisher` won't care about transmissions at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to change:

```
<transmission name="$base_to_${prefix}_trans">
<joint name="$base_to_${prefix}_leg">
```

To: ( Removing the $ ahead of the name )

```
<transmission name="base_to_${prefix}_trans">
<joint name="base_to_${prefix}_leg">
```

If the problem remains. Comment here.

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2020-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hein Wessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/53262/hein-wessels/) on 2020-04-06**:
That did the trick! I can't believe the issue was a simple copy-paste mistake. Thanks!